# I wanna hide the paragraph content automatically when the window width is 980px or smaller .Any suggession?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<p>Content1
    <a class="button" onClick="toggleText()">Read More</a>
</p> 
<p class="text2">
    Hiding content2[ maybe by toggle so even the white space is gone]     
<p>
```

By clicking the anchor link= read more, It toggles Content2.

Comment: Note: content1 and Read more are in para 1 and Content2 is in para 2

Comment: You can use css media query for this

Comment: You don't have some code to show what you tried ?

Comment: Acutally i can use opacity, visibility , but i dont want white space after it dissappears

Comment: When i was posting this question..it was in html format..

Comment: <p>     Content1     <a  onClick="hideText"> Read More</a>   </p>

Comment: <p>     Content2[i wanna hide this initially [in window width <980px] </p>

Comment: Give a class to elements to hide, and add something like `@media (max-width:980px){.class-name {visibility: hidden}}` to a stylesheet.

Comment: Then by clicking on Read more , Content 2 appears and disappears.

Comment: But the white space will be there after the text disappears

Comment: I dont want that white space after the text disappears :)

Comment: While editing your question, I tried to gues at code/prose. Please double-check to make sure that the quetion looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

For sure best way is CSS media query, but if you want to do that on js side you can add an event listener to window resize. Base on event prop you can check size of the window like this

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
      if (e.target.innerWidth < 980) {
       // do stuff  
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : .....) and (max-width : 980px) {
    .text2 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```